# Confused about how to add a product with different variables in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to sell a product with 8 colors and two sizes.
Making a configurable product means making 16 simple products!

When I need to update the prices, I have to update the price of 16 products!!
Using the bundle product and adding the size and colors (for the customer to choose) has the limitation of quantity (I need to know how many products with the specific color is left).

Is there any other way to handle that?

Comment: Yes, configurable product sounds like the right option. An extension like [Mass Product Actions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mass-product-actions-by-amasty.html) can make administration of many simple products very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this i think creating a custom option for the product would be the best idea. It is easier to create and very helful in these type of situation. Think about that. If you have same options for other product than there is an extension called **Custom Option replicator** which will help you to replicate the custom options.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. I think that would be the best way.